# Disappearing header

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, excel

I am trying to perform a join on a zip code .shp and a table that contains the same GEOID10 zip code column along with some diagnosis counts by month/year. The fields for all the dx mo/yr columns appear in the "Choose the field in the table to base the join on" drop down...but the field in my spreadsheet that needs to be there is missing.  I've made sure the numbers are all right-aligned and that the "Format cell" type is set to Number with zero decimal places in the GEOID10 column on the table I'm trying to join to the zip .shp. I can't find any documentation that adresses this. Does anybody know what's up?

Comment: Try exporting/import the spreadsheet to a file geodatabase as a table and then join. Make sure data type of the fields are the same

Comment: BERA...I tried this and the issue remains.

Comment: GEOID in the zip .shp is 'string' and GEOID in the .xls is 'double'...and I'm not finding any info on how to change it to 'string' in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to change your excel field to a string:

1. Right click your field in excel, format cells, category : text, press OK, save. It is now a text field when opened
2. When importing a table into a geodatabase, you can right click the field and select its field type, the resulting field in the table in the geodatabase will be that type.